# Abrir programas do system32 pelo C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Estou tentado executar o Active Directory da minha máquina via C#. Consigo abrir todos os outros programas comuns sem problema. 
O programa está instalado em `C:\Windows\system32\dsa.msc`, porém o Visual Studio mostra um erro e informa que **não encontrou esse arquivo**, mesmo ele existindo.

Estou executando da seguinte forma:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\system32\dsa.msc");
```

Caminho no Windows:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Erro do Visual Basic:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se existisse não iria dar este erro.

Comment: ele existe, pois se jogo no executar ele abre o programa direto.

Comment: Bem, mostre **exatamente** o erro e uma screenshot do arquivo mostrando o caminho completo dele

Comment: Tente assim `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("dsa.msc");`

Comment: @MurariAlex Tentei dessa forma e também não conseguiu encontrar o arquivo.

Comment: @LINQ Adicionei as fotos na pergunta.

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema era que tinha que definir a versão do SO no visual . Defini apenas para 64 Bits e funcionou.

Comment: Posta sua solução em resposta para os próximos usuários que tiverem o mesmo problema resolverem fácil também. Abs

Comment: @GuilhermeIA Me desculpe, já coloquei no lugar certo porem não consigo marcar como solução.

Comment: Fique tranquilo @BrunoFelipeKouuds, quando você tiver a pontuação minima para votar certo você volta aqui e vota. Só de deixar a solução para os próximos usuários já vale. Abraços!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver tirando a seleção da opções "peferir 32 bits" na Build da Properties.

A questão era que por algum motivo ele não tava encontrando devido a versão do S.O. definida no Properties do visual Studio.

[image: Solução]